# Flexslider and Easytabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I want the tab to cycle to the next tab when the slider reach the last item.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bucek/cpmvd/). I put `flexslider` carousel inside `jquery` easytabs.

Since I'm just a beginner, this is my script:

```
if (target === slider.last) {
  EASYTABS MOVE AUTOMATICLY TO THE NEXT TAB       
}
```

---

revision

i'm sorry. i just have one easytab with 4 tab(panel) which every one of them have a carousel. i want cycle them when the flexslider reach the last item. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm interpreting your question correctly: you have a flexslider slideshow and a set of easytabs tabs on a page, and you want the next tab selected each time the slideshow reaches the end, on a permanent loop, correct?

If so ...

Flexslider has a callback called 'end' that fires when the slideshow reaches the last slide, so you'll want to bind a method that increments your tab to that with something like the following in your flexslider invocation:

```
// an array of the selectors for the tabs themselves
easyTabSelectors = ['#tab-1','#tab-1','#tab-1'];

// a reference to the currently active tab by index in the array easyTabSelectors
currentEasyTab = 0;

// create your flexslider
$("#flexslider-container").flexslider({

  //Put all your other flexslider config stuff here

  // bind to the 'end' callback
  end: function () {
    currentEasyTab++; // increment the currentEasyTab variable

    // if the currentEasyTab is now a tab too far, start over
    if (currentEasyTab = easyTabSelectors.length)
      currentEasyTab = 0;

    // use the easytab 'select' method to select the next tab using the array and reference
    $('#easy-tab-container').easytabs('select', easyTabSelectors[currentEasyTab]);
  }
});
```

If you were looking for the slideshow to also stop looping at that point, you can do that, too. Flexslider has a lot of methods and callbacks to work with.

References:
 - flexslider docs / advanced / All available FlexSlider properties: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/
 - easytabs public method to select a tab: http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/#public-methods